# How to build/run Java files in VSC with inputs

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, javac

> So I just switched from Sublime to VSC wanting to try it out.

**But I'm having some trouble running Java files.**

I've done the Code Runner method but the problem is that **only** outputs code, 
no way to input commands.

I save my Java files to different folders depending on their use (some are HW Assignments for example) so messing with file locations and such in VS isn't really an option.

**Anyone know if there is a *simple* way to build & run Java files all within VSC?**

**Thanks!**

Edit: When I try to run it the other way (via debugger) I get the following error:

'C:\Users\micha.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-java-debug-0.22.0\scripts\launcher.bat' 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2\bin\java' '-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=localhost:58133' '--enable-preview'
'-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' '-cp' 'C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Temp\vscodesws_8f2d5\jdt_ws\jdt.ls-java-project\bin' 'AssignmentTest'
Error: Could not find or load main class AssignmentTest
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: AssignmentTest

Comment: After installing the JDK, you would need to configure your environment for Java development.have you set it ?

Comment: If you mean configure as in set the registry for it then yes I have, I am able to use java and javac commands through Powershell. Just having an issue with VSC

Comment: maybe you could try to refer to this [tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial)